# Elasticsearch DSL limit filter returning more results than specified

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Pretty new to elasticsearch, and json in general.

I am using elasticsearch-dsl-py, here are the docs for search: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/docs/search_dsl.rst

here is sample code:

```
q = F("limit", value=1)
s = Account.search().filter(q)
response = s.execute()
for hit in response:
    print hit
```

the above will return:

```
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
{'account': u'debug', 'proxy': u'127.0.0.1:8888', 'created_d...}
```

Don't understand why it's returning more than 1 result.

Comment: As written, this line: `q = F("limit", value=1)` accomplishes nothing.

Comment: doh.  fixed code.  it's still an issue though :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an easier way to do what you're looking for is to use slices, which the Search class supports.

```
search = Account.search()
response = search[:1].execute()
for hit in response:
    print hit
```

Comment: the splitting works for me! thanks.  tried the filter('term', limit=1) tho, still having issues with that.  glad I have something to work with tho. thanks!